# Setting up Solr with Jetty issue on Centos 6

Tags: java, solr, jetty

Here are the steps made:

1 Got Solr:

> wget http://my.mirror.com/apache.org/lucene/solr/4.6.1/solr-4.6.1.tgz

1. Unziped in /root/solr/
2. Installed jetty 6:

> Step 1 : Enable the jpackage repo Download the jpackage.repo file to
>   your /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory.
>
> ## cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
>
> ## wget http://jpackage.org/jpackage50.repo
>
> Step 2 : Install the jetty package you want
>
> ## yum search jetty will show you a list of jetty packages you want to install. At the time of writing you get 2 options - jetty 5 and
>
> jetty 6. We installed jetty 6.
>
> ## yum install jetty6

1. Copied /example/solr to /home/solr
2. Copied /example/solr/contexts to /usr/share/jetty6/contexts
3. Copied /dist/solr.war to /usr/share/jetty6/webapps
4. Copied start.jar in my /home/solr directory
5. Switched to the above directory and ran:

> java -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/solr -jar start.jar

Got the exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No XML configuration files specified in
>   start.config or command line.
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:502)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
>
> Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
>          java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are going to use jetty, I think you are better off using the version that comes bundled  with solr.

Just follow the example/README.txt and you will start solr with bundled jetty (it is jetty8 btw). Advantages are that it is properly tunned/configured for Solr, and it is the most used container for Solr in my experience.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, the only point is that I would like to start custom from start to finish. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

2nd to @Persimmonium as there might be more things to check if start from scratch.

On the other hand, just trying to address the exception as you saw, likely the **"-Djetty.home"** need to be configured (to the dir that has lib, etc dirs for holding jetty libs/configurations. The default is **.** or **..**

[**Reference 1**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Start.jar#Building_the_Environment)

Also the **Solr 4.6** has been tested with **jetty8**. It's not clear if jettey6+Solr4.6 will work out of the box. It would be interesting to learn that from your experiment.

Comment: It doesn't. I've made it with tomcat 6.